# How to find closest elements to each other in two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

Given two dataframes:

```
df_1:

c1, c2
a, 0
b, 0
c, 2

df_2:

c3, c4
d, 2
e, 3
f, 7
```

How would you find the closest c2 row to the closest c4 row, and create a new dataframe which has these in corresponding rows next to each other?

Example output:

```
a, d (zero is closest to two)
b, d (second entry of zero counts as being closest to two)
c, d (this is the closest)
```

Comment: use `pd.merge_asof` : ``pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on ='c2', right_on = 'c4', direction = 'nearest')``

Answer (score -1):

You could start by creating a new dataFrame which is a copy of your original dataframe containing `c1, c2`.

Then by using an apply function on the `c2` column, you can use the following command to find the closest value and assign it to another column.

`result_index = df['col_to_search'].sub(search_value).abs().idxmin()`